# Core audio - audio unit - compressor / limiter

Tags: ios, objective-c, signal-processing, core-audio, audiounit

I would like to implement a simple audio compressor / limiter in an iOS app. I am using core audio and audio units to do this and I've tried the Peak Limiter audio unit. What would you recommend for the best result? I want to use a compressor / limiter mostly on voice recordings, to compress peak values above a certain value.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have tested so far? You're asking for general opinions. Please improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Core Audio to implement the compressor limiter together with The Amazing Audio Engine + Audio Units: http://theamazingaudioengine.com/

This solution, though not easy to implement, seems to be working perfectly.